# LocalSessionFactoryBean with annotated mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I am not so strong in Spring.

I have a bean

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/my/company/service/impl/entity/User.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The User.hbm.xml has references to class (*UserAddress*) that has not Hibernate mapping class (*like UserAddress.hbm.xml*). Instead of this the *UserAddress* has **annotations** in it class for mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_address")
public class UserAddress extends Base {
 ...
}
```

So the question is: how can I add *UserAddress* to *sessionFactory* bean ?

Comment: What version of spring and hibernate are you using? You second example is a JPA entity which is usually configured in a persistence unit xml or in spring itself depending on the spring version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. Instead of using *org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean* it is needed to use it child: *org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean*