# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: in spring orm

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-orm

I am getting following exception

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.sample.Student

I have seen so many answers to same question on Stackoverflow but all of them suggests to use @Entity annotation from javax.persistence instead of hibernate, in my case I am using it from javax.persistence only but still getting this exception.

my POJO class

```
package com.sample;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class Student {

    @Id
    int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

and my Manger class

```
   package com.sample;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

public class ORMManager {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE");
    ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    ds.setUsername("system");
    ds.setPassword("tiger");

    LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    lsfb.setDataSource(ds);
    HibernateTemplate template = new HibernateTemplate();
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
    prop.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    prop.put("hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

    lsfb.setHibernateProperties(prop);
    try {
        lsfb.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    template.setSessionFactory((SessionFactory)lsfb.getObject());
    template.afterPropertiesSet();

    Student s = new Student();
    s.setFirstName("pallavi");
    s.setLastName("sing");
    template.save(s);
    System.out.println("done");


    }

}
```

please help me resolve this issue

Comment: Do you have a persistence.xml file?

Comment: no I donot have persistence.xml because I am not using EntityManger sorry for my knowledge I am just trying to learn

Comment: by default it takes Entity name as Table name so thats no required I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to mix two things

> Annotations

and

> LocalSessionFactoryBean

use the child class of LocalSessionFactoryBean that is

> AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

replace this

> LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

with

```
  AnnotationSessionFactoryBean lsfb = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
  Class [] annotatedClasses =  {Student.class};
  lsfb.setAnnotatedClasses(annotatedClasses);
```

or

```
  AnnotationSessionFactoryBean lsfb = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();    
  annotationSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.sample"});
```

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672580/localsessionfactorybean-with-annotated-mapping)

Comment: Add your package annotationSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.sample"});

Comment: Class [] annotatedClasses =  {
    Student.class
  };
 lsfb.setAnnotatedClasses(annotatedClasses);

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();` with the following

```
     AnnotationSessionFactoryBean annotationSessionFactoryBean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
     annotationSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.sample"});
```