# HibernatePagingItemReader throwing QuerySyntaxException table is not mapped

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am developing using spring-boot, spring-batch application where I am reading data from source table using HibernatePagingItemReader. When I am running the code I am getting below exception. Below is my application code. Please note that my table name in database is "OLDUSER" and my entity name is "Olduser". I have already used all the possible suggestions made over stackoverflow for similar questions but none of them is working me.
Thanks for the help.

```
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Olduser is not mapped [FROM Olduser o where o.id>=7501 and o.id <= 15000 order by o.id ASC]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
```

**Domain class : Olduser.java:-**

```
    import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Table(name="OLDUSER")
@Entity
public class Olduser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    int id;
    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    String username;
    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    String password;
    @Column(name="AGE")
    int age;

    public Olduser(int id, String username, String password, int age) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.age = age;
    }
```

**ItemReader Code :-**

```
        @Bean
@StepScope
public HibernatePagingItemReader<Olduser> hibernateUserItemReader(
        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}") final String fromId,
        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}") final String toId,
        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[name]}") final String name) throws Exception {

    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = factoryBean.getObject();

    HibernatePagingItemReader<Olduser> hibernateReader=new HibernatePagingItemReader<>();
    hibernateReader.setFetchSize(chunkSize);
    hibernateReader.setQueryString("FROM Olduser o where o.id>=" + fromId + " and o.id <= " + toId +" order by o.id ASC");
    hibernateReader.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    hibernateReader.setUseStatelessSession(false);
    hibernateReader.setSaveState(false);
    hibernateReader.afterPropertiesSet();
    return hibernateReader;
}
```

Comment: Check if answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629702/org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity-in-spring-orm?noredirect=1&lq=1 is good for your problem

Comment: Hi @LucaBassoRicci , Thanks for your help, I have already found the solution of the problem.I have added the annotatedpackages and also I have to add bean JPATransactionManager to manage transaction for LocalSessionFactoryBean. I will post the complete solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution of the above. I missed to add annotatedpackages in the LocalSessionFactoryBean that is the reason context was unable to locate the Entity class. Also I was missing the transactionManager classs which is to manage the transaction. Below is the code snippet.

Created a separate bean sessionFactory and added the same in hibernatePagingItemReader

```
    hibernateReader.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
```

SessionFactory Bean :-

```
    @Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws IOException{
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("package name");
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factoryBean;
}
```

TransactionManager bean :-

```
     @Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
}
```